# Progressisvely create arrays js

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

So I am creating a game where a spaceship moves and it must avoid a fireball image in order to win. My issue is that I only got one fireball and instead, I would like to have many fireballs, which are multiplicate as time passes. I think I should need to incorporate an array and use push() method but I tried and I just couldn't do it. If anyone could help me, it would be very appreciated. Thanks

```
//Fireball script
function fireballScript(offset) {
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (window.innerWidth - offset))}
let fireballMovement = {x: fireballScript(fireball.offsetWidth), y: 0}
const fireLoop = function() {
fireballMovement.y += 1
fireball.style.top = fireballMovement.y + 'px'
if (fireballMovement.y > window.innerHeight) {
fireballMovement.x = fireballScript(fireball.offsetWidth)
fireball.style.left = fireballMovement.x + 'px'
fireballMovement.y = 0
fireball.setAttribute('hit', false)}}
fireball.style.left = fireballMovement.x + 'px'
let fireballSpeed = setInterval(fireLoop, 1000 / 250)

let fireball = document.querySelector("#fireball")

<img src="Photo/fireball.png" id="fireball">
```

Also, please consider this script:

```
//Stop game on collision
function checkCollision() {
if (detectOverlap(spaceship, fireball) && fireball.getAttribute('hit') == 'false') {
hits++
fireball.setAttribute('hit', true)
alert("lost")}
setTimeout(checkCollision, 1)}
var detectOverlap = (function() {
function getPositions(spaceship) {
var pos = spaceship.getBoundingClientRect()
return [[pos.left, pos.right], [pos.top, pos.bottom]]}
function comparePositions(p1, p2) {
let r1 = p1[0] < p2[0] ? p1 : p2
let r2 = p1[0] < p2[0] ? p2 : p1
return r1[1] > r2[0] || r1[0] === r2[0]}
return function(a, b) {
var pos1 = getPositions(a), pos2 = getPositions(b)
return comparePositions(pos1[0], pos2[0]) && comparePositions(pos1[1], pos2[1])}})()

let spaceship = document.querySelector("#icon")
<img src="Photo/Spaceship1.png" id="icon">
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add more fireballs to your page

```
function addFireball() {
  var newFireball = document.createElement('div')
  newFireball.className = 'fireball' // Set whatever props you want
  document.body.appendChild(newFireball)
}
```

You'll also want to keep track of them ( you can do this in your addFireball method)

```
var fireballs = []
…
function addFireball() {
  …
  document.body.appendChild(newFireball)
  fireballs.push(newFireball)
}
```

This isn't a complete answer - we'd need more information about your project. But hopefully this at least gets you going again!